# Как подключиться к SMTP серверу yandex на Windows VDS?

Tags: python, windows, smtp, vds

На windows-vds пытаюсь подключиться к SMTP серверу Яндекса.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.yandex.ru', port=465)
```

В трейсе возвращает ошибку `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]...`, которая возникает на этапе `create_connection sock.connect`
Для 465 порта в брандмауэре правило на вход установлено.

Comment: Полное отключение брандмауэра так же не помогло.
На локальной машине все работает отлично.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, я написал неправильно

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать установить тайм-аут:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.yandex.ru', port=465, timeout=120)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, к сожалению проблему не решает